# Error al intentar introducir una fecha en una columna tipo "date" en la base de datos

Tags: javascript, postgresql

Tengo una columna tipo `date` e intento insertar un fecha pero me arroja el siguiente error:

> Invalid parameter value: 7 ERROR:  el huso horario «gmt-0400» no es reconocido (SQL: insert into "lotes" ("numero", "id_productos", "fecha", "id_turnos", "updated_at", "created_at") values (700011, 4, Tue Mar 07 2017 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Hora estándar oeste, Sudamérica), 11, 2017-03-07 18:37:48, 2017-03-07 18:37:48) returning "id")

El problema es el uso horario, como puedo eliminarlo en javascript.

Tengo un `string` con el siguiente formato: `dd/mm/año` un ej de este es: `07/03/2017` lo paso a una fecha con `new Date()` y me queda de la sig manera: `Tue Mar 07 2017 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Hora estándar oeste, Sudamérica)`

El codigo es el sig:

```
var fechaInput = $('#crear_fecha').val();
var fecha = new Date(fecha);
```

NOTA: no se que es mejor solucionar, el javascript o modificar la columna de la DB.

Comment: Mira un ejemplo de Postgresql: `INSERT INTO films (code, title, did, date_prod, kind) VALUES ('T_601', 'Yojimbo', 106, '1961-06-16', 'Drama');` convierte tu fecha a `aaaa-mm-dd` usando guiones, no / ... es todo lo que necesitas pasarle, y no todo lo que creas con `new Date (fecha);`

Comment: Yo te aconsejaría cambiar el tipo de dato de la Bd, dado que hay veces del front-end que viene basura y esta no la puedes transformar. Yo al final tuve que poner un varchar.

Answer (score 1):

Debes transformar tu fecha al formato correcto. Para eso puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime($fecha));
```

En donde fecha es el `string` proporcionado por por `javascript`. En su defecto, en lugar de generar la fecha por `javascript`, podrías generar la fecha desde `PHP`:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO mytable (fecha) VALUES ('".date('Y-m-d H:i:s')."')";
```

Comment: Es posible que tengas que modificar también la tabla para que acepte valores tipo 'datetime', de lo contrario únicamente almacenará la fecha y no la hora.

Answer (score 0):

Para esto puedes transformar tu objeto "Date" a un string usando la siguiente funcion: fecha.toLocaleDateString();

```js
//var fechaInput = $('#crear_fecha').val();
var fecha = new Date("5/2/2010").toLocaleDateString();
console.log(fecha)
```

Así te devolvera un string de una fecha en el mismo formato de la que enviaste. Ej: 3/8/2017